# Apple Mail Mailboxes missing

Tags: macos, mail.app

Apple Mail crashed and I rebuilt the database. It now works but my mailboxes are missing. How can missing mailboxes be restored?

Answer (score 1):

The only way this can be restored if you have a Time Machine backup or another backup which included mail.

- [Restore items backed up with Time Machine on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mh11422/mac)

This way all MailBox folders and messages will be restored.

> If you set up Time Machine to back up files on your Mac, you can use the backups to restore lost mailboxes and email messages.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/restore-mailboxes-and-their-content-mail15172/mac